# group list to datatable with dynamic row

Tags: c#, .net

I have a list like following:

```
public static List<Record> initRecords() {
    var list = new List<Record>();
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "aaa", FieldName = "First Name", FieldValue = "Joey"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "aaa", FieldName = "Last Name", FieldValue = "Williams"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "aaa", FieldName = "Company", FieldValue = "Microsoft"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "bbbb", FieldName = "First Name", FieldValue = "Larry"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "bbbb", FieldName = "Last Name", FieldValue = "Johnson"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "bbbb", FieldName = "Company", FieldValue = "Knicks"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "bbbb", FieldName = "Comment", FieldValue = "4-1"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "ccc", FieldName = "First Name", FieldValue = "Allen"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "ccc", FieldName = "Last Name", FieldValue = "Houston"});
    list.Add(new Record {UserID = "ccc", FieldName = "Company", FieldValue = "Lala"});

    return list;
}
```

And I use LINQ to group them to three group by their UserID, as you can see, the record count for each group is different

```
var records = list.GroupBy(u => u.UserID).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();
```

it's all good by now, but I need some guidance to construct this grouped list to a datatable, so I can transform it to a html table like following, tks

--addon:
Maybe I wasn't explain it clearly, the list is a dynamic list, a grouped list can have many "FieldName" 
What I'm trying to do is to group the list with UserID, then select one list with the max count "FieldName", transform them to "DataTable Columns" then loop every grouped list records to DataTable.NewRow

something like this

### First Name | Last Name | Company | Comment

Joey         Williams    Microsoft

then I can loop it into html table

Comment: INSERT INTO MyTable (FirstName, LastName, Company, Comment) VALUES(.....), (.....), (....)

Comment: Are you using ASP.net or Razor MVC?  Both of those have syntax for looping through collections on your html page.  You should look up how to loop through a list on the html page for whichever framework you are using.  Why do you feel the need to put your list of Records into a datatable object?